# SQL Error : integrity constraint violation : foreign key no parent

Tags: java, sql, foreign-keys

I'm struggling to find what I'm doing wrong with my query.
I did not create the database but here is the structure :

3 TABLES :

**vehicule** : brand, motor, price, name, id

**option** : id, description, price

**vehicule_option** : id_vehicule, id_option

I guess that vehicule_option has 2 foreign keys but I can not find the problem with my addings.
Here's my code which first part works fine :

```
public boolean create(Vehicule v){
        String query = "INSERT INTO vehicule (MARQUE, MOTEUR, PRIX, NOM) VALUES (";
        query += v.getMarque().getId() + ", "
                + v.getMoteur().getId() + ", "
                + v.getPrix() + ", \'"
                + v.getNom() + "\');";

        for (Option o : v.getOptions()){
            query += "INSERT INTO vehicule_option (id_vehicule, id_option) VALUES ("
                    + v.getId() + ", " + o.getId() + ");";
        }


        try{
            Statement state = this.connect.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = state.executeQuery(query);
        } catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

So, what I'm doing here is basically INSERT two values into the right columns.
It gives me the following exception :

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: integrity constraint violation: foreign key no parent; SYS_FK_10132 table: VEHICULE_OPTION
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at fr.ocr.sql.DAOVehicule.create(DAOVehicule.java:35)
    at fr.ocr.ihm.AddCarDialogBox$1.actionPerformed(AddCarDialogBox.java:151)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: integrity constraint violation: foreign key no parent; SYS_FK_10132 table: VEHICULE_OPTION
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Constraint.getException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Constraint.checkInsert(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.performIntegrityChecks(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.insertSingleRow(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementInsert.getResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDMQL.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 40 more
```

Comment: Did you ever call `v.setId`?  If not, it's unlikely to have the same value as the id in the database.

Comment: I just had goosebumps. Yet another invitation to lose all your data by [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: I think it is v.getId() that's making a problem. It gives 0 when the ID into the database has to be something like 20

Comment: @Andreas LOL, since it is an offline SWING application, I'm not worried :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just inserted a new `vehicule` record, so how would you know the id of that record in `v.getId()`?

You don't, and `v.getId()` is likely `0`, since you're creating a new one.

Comment: this is right indeed. Now I'm facing a problem. Could you help me with that? I don't get it neither.. I'm editing my question.

Comment: @YassinHajaj Please don't change the question after you already have two answers.  If you have a new question, then please ask a new question.  Otherwise, you make a mockery of the good answers you've already been given.

Comment: @DavidWallace Ok, I'm making a new question.

Answer (score 3):

From what you have shown here, it looks like vehicle option has two foreign keys the id from the vehicle table and the id from the options table.

When you do your insert either the vehicle id is not present in the vehicle table or the option id is not in its option table.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are iterating by "o" variable you should use o.getId() instead of v.getId()