# SQL : Vehicule gets added to DataBase but not his options

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, hsqldb

This question is the continuity of this one :

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32922870/sql-error-integrity-constraint-violation-foreign-key-no-parent)

I'm not having any exception thrown anymore. Data gets added to the `vehicule` table but not to the `vehicule_option` table.

Do you have any idea why?

```
public boolean create(Vehicule v){
    String query = "INSERT INTO vehicule (MARQUE, MOTEUR, PRIX, NOM) VALUES (";
    query += v.getMarque().getId() + ", "
            + v.getMoteur().getId() + ", "
            + v.getPrix() + ", \'"
            + v.getNom() + "\');";

    try{
        connect.setAutoCommit(false);
        ResultSet nextID = connect.prepareStatement("CALL NEXT VALUE FOR seq_vehicule_id").executeQuery();
        if (nextID.next()){
            int ID = nextID.getInt(1);
            v.setId(ID-1);
        }

        for (Option o : v.getOptions()){
            System.out.println(v.getId() + " " + o.getId());
            query += "INSERT INTO vehicule_option (id_vehicule, id_option) VALUES ("
                    + v.getId() + ", " + o.getId() + ");";
        }

        Statement state = this.connect.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = state.executeQuery(query);

    } catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Here's an example of query I get with this code :

```
INSERT INTO vehicule (MARQUE, MOTEUR, PRIX, NOM) VALUES (0, 0, 250.0, 'test');
INSERT INTO vehicule_option (id_vehicule, id_option) VALUES (34, 0);
INSERT INTO vehicule_option (id_vehicule, id_option) VALUES (34, 1);
INSERT INTO vehicule_option (id_vehicule, id_option) VALUES (34, 2);
INSERT INTO vehicule_option (id_vehicule, id_option) VALUES (34, 3);
INSERT INTO vehicule_option (id_vehicule, id_option) VALUES (34, 4);
```

Comment: I'm not certain of this, but I don't think you can execute a bunch of statements separated by semicolons in the way you're trying to do it.  You should execute each statement individually.

Comment: Are you committing the transaction? You're setting `setAutoCommit(false)` but I don't see anywhere you call `commit()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the updated code below. See the comments inline:

```
public boolean create(Vehicule v) {
        String query = "INSERT INTO vehicule (MARQUE, MOTEUR, PRIX, NOM) VALUES (";
        query += v.getMarque().getId() + ", " + v.getMoteur().getId() + ", "
                + v.getPrix() + ", \'" + v.getNom() + "\')";

        try {
            connect.setAutoCommit(false);
            ResultSet nextID = connect.prepareStatement(
                    "CALL NEXT VALUE FOR seq_vehicule_id").executeQuery();
            if (nextID.next()) {
                int ID = nextID.getInt(1);
                v.setId(ID - 1);
            }

            /* Save vehicle */
            Statement state = this.connect.createStatement();
            state.executeUpdate(query);

            /* Now start with creating query for vehicle_option. Execute only if collection not empty */
            if (!v.getOptions().isEmpty()) {
                query = "INSERT INTO vehicule_option (id_vehicule, id_option) VALUES ";
                boolean valueAdded = false;
                for (Option o : v.getOptions()) {
                    System.out.println(v.getId() + " " + o.getId());
                    if (valueAdded) {
                        query += ", ";
                    }
                    query += "(" + v.getId() + ", " + o.getId() + ")";
                    valueAdded = true;
                }

                state = this.connect.createStatement();
                state.executeUpdate(query);
            }
            /* Commit inserts if all queries executed fine */
            connect.commit();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Suggests you to replace String concatenation with `StringBuilder` for query building.

Comment: This code doesn't work James but you put me on the right path, the answer was actually to put connect.setAutoCommit(true) after the if test, it works fine now. I'm editing your answer btw

Comment: I do not see the reason why you said it doesn't work.

Comment: because it threw the same exact exception. And i'm being rude right now, Thank you for the effort put and the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I would expect a

```
std.execute(sql);
```

every time you like to insert something, the executeQuery is for "SELECT" ResultSet,

I give some suggestions to improve your code

1. Place the statement outside of the try catch (you need to close it on finally).
2. Every time you like to insert use statement.execute(sql). (hence you will have one before your loop to insert the vehicule and one inside of your loop for all the vehicule_option (this could be also improved using prepared statment but lets leave that for now).
3. To get the id of an inserted record search for [statement generated keys](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html), not saying your metod does not work but this way you avoid query (if db supports generated key)

Comment: Actually, the first part of the query works fine cause the vehicule is inserted. v.getOptions() has options in it, I did a print to make sure

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see is when you first `CALL NEXT VALUE FOR seq_vehicule_id` you get an ID but that wouldnt be the same as the one for `vehicule_option`.

Beside you do an (ID-1) `dont know why?` the next thing get executed is the `INSERT INTO vehicule` that also generate a new `seq_vehicule_id`

So if you start with `seq_id = 10` then `next value` will be `11` you get `id-1 -> 10` for option... and `INSERT INTO vehicule` will use `12`

So my recomendation get the `vehicule_id` and `INSERT INTO vehicule values (Vehicule_Id` instead of use the default.

Also would be great if you show us the final string for `query`. Unlike other comment I think you can do `query1; query2;` without problems. But with the final query string you can validate the syntaxis is ok direct on DB.

Comment: Hi ! The ID is exactly the same, I checked it. I edited my post to show an example of query I get.

Comment: what you mean `edit code`? That is using single back quote `\`` between the text you want highlight.You try run that code in db?

Comment: Looks like the only thing you are missing is `connect.commit();`

Comment: Indeed, it has something to do with commit(), actually, I had to write connect.setAutoCommit(true) after my If